# Address Standardization Tool

Tags: visualforce, address

I have a Visualforce Page for the Force.Com Site
Through this Page we are creating Accounts (pretty much, Web to Account).
What is the best tool to Standardize address that comes through Web form into Salesforce. 
I don't want to create Validation rule as it will prevent the Accounts from being created in Salesforce.

Does anyone have a recommendation for a tool or any other function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably want to start with a check on the [AppExchange](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxSearchKeywordResults?keywords=address%20validation&searchType=simpleSearch). There's a lot of solutions already built for your use case. They range in quality and price, so please do some research. Alternatively, you could always use Google or some other map provider API to validate addresses. Please note that almost all solutions will have some associated cost.

Comment: Thank You @sfdcfox